# JavaScript sample code

Tags: javascript

Please see the site:

http://www.ibsolution.de/irj/portal//dsag_2010

On the page there's a tab section, where you can click any of the following tabs:

- Info Anmeldung
- Unsere Vorträge
- Unsere Partners

Is this created using JavaScript?

I also want integrate something like this on my website. What do you call this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

It's just simple toggling of elements using the click event on the anchors.

Comment: thanks, so this is jquery not with javascript then? is this correct?

Comment: jQuery *IS* Javascript. You can code it yourself in JS but it's much more time conserving to use jQuery.

Comment: ok this looks cool but then i'm wondering if i can integrate it with my cms modx.i tried it but it didn't work:(

Comment: You have not spent enough time integrating if you've only taken 10 minutes. You're rushing things without understanding it properly, and not explaining what you tried.

Comment: yeah my bad. just need to finish some work here.trying to understand but these all seems difficult.coz i need to ask someone that's why. btw, wondering where you can edit the colors and backgrounds of the tab?